# Sympy Lambdify with array inputs

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to give an array as input and expect an array as output for the following code.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
import os
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

text=open('expr.txt','r')
expr=text.read()
x,param1,param2=symbols('x param1 param2')
params=np.array([param1,param2])
T=lambdify((x,params),expr,modules='numpy')
data=np.genfromtxt('datafile.csv',delimiter=',')
print T(data[0],[0.29,4.5])
text.close()
```

But get the following error.

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 3 arguments (13 given)
```

How do i tell sympy that its a single array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I see a lot of errors in your code. The variable expr is just a string not an expression.

Comment: Its a mathematical expression involving x, param1 and param2, in a file. I am trying to evaluate it at different values of x, given param1 and param2

Comment: how does the expression look like?

Comment: 2*param1/param2*(x**(param2-1)-x**(-1-param2/2))

Comment: Could you post what's in data[0]?

Comment: data[0] is an array.
array([ 1.  ,  0.97,  0.94,  0.91,  0.88,  0.85,  0.82,  0.79,  0.76,
        0.73,  0.7 ])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Solution:**
Your problem is, that the function T expects a value, but you are handing out a list. Try this instead of `print T(data[0],[0.29,4.5])`to get a list of results:

```
print [T(val,[0.29,4.5]) for val in data[0]]
```

Or use a wrapper function:

```
def arrayT(array, params):
    return [T(val, params) for val in array]

print arrayT(data[0], [0.29, 4.5])
```

---

**2. Solution:** You have to change your mathematical expression. Somehow sympy doesn't work with list of lists, so try this:

```
expr = "2*y/z*(x**(z-1)-x**(-1-z/2))"
T=lambdify((x,y,z),expr,'numpy')

print T(data[0], 0.29, 4.5)
```

Comment: I've tried that and it works too, but the problem is I evaluate T elsewhere with different arrays eachtime and so need a mathematical expression that is capable of taking in arrays and giving out arrays.

Comment: Why does the mathematical function need to be capable of taking in arrays. Couldn't you just define a wrapper function?

Comment: Second solution isn't working, still get the same error. Used double square brackets

Comment: The first solution isn't a viable option because i have a function that outputs the expression. There are other expressions involved too that i've already coded in. I am currently working on a case where the user gets to give his own mathematical model(expression). I have to use the particular model(expression) chosen by the user, so i need to get the expression working with arrays.

Comment: I think I got it. I updated the second solution. It works on my machine.

Comment: Any idea why sympy is allowing only one array in its input?

Comment: It alowes more than one array. But not array of arrays. For example: `T(array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6]),array([7,8,9]))` would also work.